# How to follow symbolic link with smb share

Tags: permissions, samba

I have a Virtual machine running Ubuntu server 14.04 and I've set up some smb shares.

Everything is working fine except for following symbolic links. The host is a Mac and I can see the symbolic link but I get permission denied if trying to access it.

I have added this to the global settings and the share itself, but it seems to make no difference:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes
```

This is the share:

```
[myshare]
   comment = Myshare
   browseable = yes
   path = /home/myuser/Myshare
   printable = no
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 2777
   writable = yes
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
```

The share itself I did a chmod 777, the symbolic link was 755, tried 777 as well but it seems to make no difference. I'm not really sure what I'm missing here. As a temporary workaround I just created another share to where the symbolic link points to but I'd rather just have the single share.

Comment: This question may have an answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path